# Safari not automatically translating web page

Tags: html, safari

I have a PWA that displays some data in Italian language (you can see it here: https://2dance.app/public/menu/7/118/91).

I want that when a user navigates to the given page, if Italian is not their native language, they can automatically translate the page using Google Translate or Safari translate, according to which mobile device they are using.

In order to do that, I put in my HTML this attribute:

```
<html lang="it">
```

On Android, Google Translate pops up as expected, and the translation works fine. On the other hand, on iOS, I can't see anywhere the Safari translate feature. I've also tested this on macOS, and it's not there as well, so I think it's something related to Safari.

Do I have to add something else to my HTML to make it show up?

I've been testing with iOS 15.1 and 15.3.

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. 
I use a superscript to inject the HTML lang code into non-English pages that don't have it, to trigger Chrome to translate. But I have never found a reliable way to trigger Safari to translate.